# How do set .deb to run with synaptic?

Tags: synaptic

My problem is that i can't find synaptic when I click on more programs how to set the .deb files to run with synaptic?

Comment: You might be better to install downloaded programs with gdebi --sudo apt-get install gdebi

Comment: I agree with @arochester. synaptic was not meant to be called for specific individual packages. It's purpose is to manager many changes efficiently and to provide easy sort-and-search functionality through apt.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to install a .deb file you can use:

```
dpkg -i file.deb
```

But [`dpkg`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/dpkg.1.html) won't solve dependencies so, I would suggest you install from [`gdebi`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/gdebi.1.html):

```
gdebi file.deb
```

Comment: thnks dude :) :)

Comment: @andreas Upvote the answer if it was helpful:-)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to change default applications for any file is using of **Thunar File Manager**. Open related folder and right click then choose open with, then select Synaptic and click on set as default.

I had same problem and only Thunar can solve this case easily.